# access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to download a file into my bucket of my VM, but get the following error. How do I change the access to the access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket?  The bucket was mounted using: gcsfuse user_bucket_1 my_bucket_2

This bucket was created when I have a different VM. Does it matter?
Edit: created a new bucket, same problem.

```
(base) user@instance-1:~/my_bucket_2$ gsutil -u absolute-bison-xxxx cp gs://realigned.cram.crai gs://bucket_1 

AccessDeniedException: 403 xxxxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

Comment: I recommend you read the error closely, as it is telling you what the problem is - you don't have permissions to list the contents of the bucket with the account/credentials you're using. Perhaps start by examining what permissions currently are?

Comment: But I am not sure how and where to change those permission. I try to add all storage-related permissions on my bucket. I have added: Storage Admin
Storage Object Admin

Comment: The bucket isn't the problem. `xxxxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.`

That points to the xxxxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com account's permissions being the issue.

Comment: "cannot edit inherited roles" is what is says on my VM instance. If that's where changes need to be made..

Comment: Ok - what does that tell you? Inherited roles. There's a parent object above your VMs applying these roles to children (which include any VMs you make). Check that. You have to read the errors and then critically think about them and proceed.

Comment: If its on my IAM settings it says: Editor
Owner
Storage Admin
Storage Object Admin

Comment: Look, you have a permissions issue - that's what you need to be looking at. Nobody else can help you much further from there, as we're not in your account looking at things. Read things, research them if you have to, and then proceed. Expecting to have your hand held is unrealistic.

Comment: Solved the problem by typing: gcloud auth login

Answer (score 1):

AccessDeniedException: 403 xxxxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Looks Like the service account is creating that error. The reason why the service account is being automatically used, is because you are using the command from your GCE instance. It looks like the IAM role needs to be granted to service account : ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com’

The service account requires "storage.objects.list" in the project of the bucket. Depending on your use case, you can grant [roles/storage.objectAdmin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) or [roles/storage.admin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) in the IAM Page. [Navigation Menu >> IAM & Admin] or with [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access). These roles also contain "storage.objects.list".

'gcloud auth login' to authenticate is a great idea as well, but adding the roles might be a little easier. It's your preference.